# Mat initialization exception in java

Tags: java, opencv, exception, mat

I am using OpenCv in Java.

```
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
```

Now i'm trying to initialize a new Mat like this:

```
Mat points = new Mat();
```

What i recieve is the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:15)
```

I have no idea what this exception is about. Also no idea what i could have done wrong. Do you?

Comment: `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is thrown when native libraries are not found. Did you install OpenCV correctly?

Comment: Yes i did, i already used it in other classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i found it out.

following line is missing:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```